# Can't select different cells in same row of tableview JavaFx

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView, where I need to enable the selection of any cells(one at a time). For now, I use this code:

```
        tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            if(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null)
            {
                TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tableView.getSelectionModel();
                ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
                TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
                String val = (String)tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);
                System.out.println("Selected Value: " + val);
                selectionTextField.appendText(val);
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, I can't get the values of different cells in the same row after each other. I think it's because it's the same row, the selection listener is not triggered. I tried clearSelection(), but then I get out of bounds exception, and I read somewhere that I cant change the table model in the same listener. Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify: you want individual cell selection (instead of the default row selection)? Are you using `tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);`? Do you want multiple cells to be able to be selected at once, or just one?

Comment: I am using individual row selection and it works if I always click somewhere in a different row. .setCellSelectionEnabled(true); is set.I would like to select only one cell at a time.

Comment: If you have `.setCellSelectionEnabled(true)` then you are actually using cell selection, not row selection...

Comment: yes, I can select rows, sorry I meant that I cant get their values. Editing the question. When I continually click on different cells in same row they are selected, but the changeListener isn't triggered and I can't get the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using cell selection instead of row selection (in other words, if you have called `tableView.getSelectionMode().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);`), then you should observe the list of selected cells instead of the `selectedItem` property. The `selectedItem` property only indicates the row that is selected, so it only changes if you select a new row.

```
ObservableList<TablePosition> selectedCells = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells() ;
selectedCells.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TablePosition> change) -> {
    if (selectedCells.size() > 0) {
        TablePosition selectedCell = selectedCells.get(0);
        TableColumn column = selectedCell.getTableColumn();
        int rowIndex = selectedCell.getRow();
        Object data = column.getCellObservableValue(rowIndex).getValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: How do I get the value the cell holds though?