# JavaFX getting cell value on hover

Tags: javafx

I was searching for a solution on how to get cell values by hovering over them, but haven't found any. I was thinking of a similar solution to this:
[Can't select different cells in same row of tableview JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085555/cant-select-different-cells-in-same-row-of-tableview-javafx/) , except not selecting, but only hover. How could I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom cell that updates a property when the mouse enters/exits it:

```
public class HoverCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

    public HoverCell(StringProperty hoverProperty) {
        setOnMouseEntered(e -> hoverProperty.set(getItem()));
        setOnMouseExited(e -> hoverProperty.set(null));
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : item);
    }
}
```

Complete example:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HoverTableCells extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty);
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty);
        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = column("Email", Person::emailProperty);

        StringProperty hoveredProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new HoverCell(hoveredProperty));
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new HoverCell(hoveredProperty));
        emailCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new HoverCell(hoveredProperty));

        Label currentHover = new Label();
        currentHover.textProperty().bind(hoveredProperty);

        table.getColumns().add(firstNameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(emailCol);

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        BorderPane.setMargin(currentHover, new Insets(10));
        root.setTop(currentHover);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class HoverCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

        public HoverCell(StringProperty hoverProperty) {
            setOnMouseEntered(e -> hoverProperty.set(getItem()));
            setOnMouseExited(e -> hoverProperty.set(null));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty ? null : item);
        }
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }


        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }


        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }


        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }


        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }


        public final String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setEmail(final String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```